# CASE WHEN syntax SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with `CASE WHEN` syntax in SQL Server. Am I doing wrong from the following syntax? I use this syntax on view of SQL Server. Check the following syntax:

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID ,
    t1.ClassID ,
    t1.theDate ,
    t1.theTime ,
    t1.Number01 ,
    MAX(t2.Number01) AS Prev_Number01 ,
    CASE
        WHEN ( ( t1.Number01 -   MAX( t2.Number01 ) ) < 0
          THEN ( 100000      - ( MAX( t2.Number01 ) ) + t1.Number01 ) ,
               ( t1.Number01 -   MAX( t2.Number01 ) ) )
    END AS _Number01 ,
    t1.Number02 , 
    MAX( t2.Number02 ) AS Prev_Number02 ,
    CASE
        WHEN ( ( t1.Number02 -   MAX( t2.Number02 ) ) < 0
          THEN ( 100000      - ( MAX( t2.Number02 ) ) + t1.Number02 ) ,
               ( t1.Number02 -   MAX( t2.Number02 ) ) )
    END AS _Number02 ,
    CONVERT(Decimal(18,3) ,
        (   t1.Number01
          - MAX(t2.Number01)
        ) /
        POWER(
          POWER(
            COALESCE( t1.Number01 - MAX(t2.Number01) , 0 ) ,
            2 )
          + POWER(
              COALESCE( t1.Number02 - MAX(t2.Number02), 0) ,
              2 ) ,
          0.5
          )
        ) AS _NumberA ,
    t1.Number03 ,
    t1.Number04 ,
    t1.Number05 ,
    t1.AD ,
    t1.GM ,
    MAX(t2.GM) AS Prev_GM ,
    t1.GM - MAX(t2.GM) AS AX ,
    t1.DC ,
    t1.MW ,
    t1.ULH ,
    t1.UL ,
    CONVERT(Decimal(18,3), 
        t1.MW / POWER( POWER(t1.MW,2) + POWER(t1.UL,2) , 0.5 )
        ) AS UT ,
    t1.RE ,
    t1.FV ,
    t1.TG ,
    t1.NM ,
    t1.CK
FROM            
    dbo._CTProduction AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo._CTProduction AS t2 ON t2.ClassID  = t1.ClassID
                            AND t2.Number01 < t1.Number01
                            AND t2.Number02 < t1.Number02
                            AND t2.GM < t1.GM
GROUP BY 
    t1.ID, t1.ClassID, t1.theDate, t1.theTime,
    t1.Number01, t1.Number02, t1.Number03, t1.Number04, t1.Number05,
    t1.AD, t1.GM, t1.DC, t1.MW, t1.ULH, t1.UL,
    t1.RE, t1.FV, t1.TG, t1.NM, t1.CK
```

And this is the error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.

Also there's one more `CASE` statement on line 6. It is the same with Line 4. Anybody can help for this problem?

Comment: Did you look it up? ([CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `case` statement:

```
CASE WHEN ((t1.Number01 - MAX(t2.Number01)) < 0
     THEN (100000 - (MAX(t2.Number01)) + t1.Number01),
(t1.Number01 - MAX(t2.Number01))) END AS _Number01, t1.Number02, 
MAX(t2.Number02) AS Prev_Number02,
```

This is not correct.  I'm not sure what you want, but this is syntactically correct:

```
(CASE WHEN t1.Number01 - MAX(t2.Number01) < 0
      THEN 100000 - MAX(t2.Number01) + t1.Number01
      ELSE t1.Number01 - MAX(t2.Number01)
 END) AS _Number01, t1.Number02, 
MAX(t2.Number02) AS Prev_Number02,
```

In other words, the comma is not part of the syntax and you are missing the `else` (if that is your intention).

Comment: @Haminteu . . . You also have mismatched parentheses.  I removed the extraneous ones to simplify the query.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `ELSE` phrase. Instead you've put a comma followed by the alternative value.

```
CASE WHEN (t1.Number01 - MAX(t2.Number01)) < 0
    THEN (100000 - MAX(t2.Number01) + t1.Number01)
    ELSE (t1.Number01 - MAX(t2.Number01))
END
```

The `CASE` statement documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you reflow your code so it's something approaching readable (which see my edit above), you might notice that you got unbalanced parenthesis in both your `when` and `then` clauses. Not to mention the `then` clause trying return a comm-delimited set of values.

Comment: Hmmm, unbalanced? On which line?